# Why is my session always crashed after intall conda in Google Colab

Tags: session, installation, crash, conda, google-colaboratory

I am trying to setup and run Conda on Google Colab.
However, everytime I run the following code to install conda

```
!pip install -q condacolab 
import condacolab
condacolab.install()
```

My session would crash.
I'm doing the above because I want to use '!conda install' in Google Colab.

Is there something wrong with the code above or should I change other settings in Colab.

I'm always using GPU or TPU.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://github.com/conda-incubator/condacolab), there is forced kernel restart, which is required for the Conda installation to be integrated in the session:

> *"It is important that you perform the installation first thing in the notebook because **it will require a kernel restart, thus resetting the variables set up to that point**."* [*emphasis added*]